# iOS - Can't Read File Located In Documents Directory

Tags: ios

I am trying to read a file in which I successfully downloaded and saved in the Documents directory. However, when I try to read it, if fails.

Here is the error:

```
2016-03-28 21:00:26.585 App[569:4103] Path is /var/mobile/Applications/3AFA2430-C0DC-44CD-95F8-A89D82B2C348/Documents/combo.bin
2016-03-28 21:00:26.603 App[569:4103] Error in reading Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)" UserInfo=0x17df29d0 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/3AFA2430-C0DC-44CD-95F8-A89D82B2C348/Documents/combo.bin, NSUnderlyingError=0x17df90b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"}
```

Here is my code:

```
    NSError *error;
    NSData *firmwareContentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:FIRMWARE_LOCAL_PATH options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Path is %@", FIRMWARE_LOCAL_PATH);

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in reading %@", error);

        return;
    }
```

local path is

```
#define FIRMWARE_LOCAL_PATH [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"combo.bin"]
```

I tried using NSTemporaryDirectory(), using NSFileManager to get the contents of the file, but none of them works. Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure combo.bin is the file and not a directory? you can make sure using some explore application to analyze your iOS device directory structure (i prefer the app named iExplore)

Comment: @heximal I am 110% sure combo.bin is a file. It is the firmware we use to upgrade a device. I downloaded it from our server and then I was going to read the file and send it through socket to the device.

Comment: @heximal Ok, forget what I said earlier. You are right. I mistakenly made combo.bin a directory. I thought I should pass a full path including the file name into the download method. Didn't thought of that. Thank you for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a permissions error. You don't have the right permissions to open the file. Wherever you got it from, you're locked out.  You might try to download it in the simulator, and check it through Apple's file system to see what permissions it actually downloaded with.  The path is:

~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Containers/Data/Application//Documents.

Replace the two big random strings with the directories that show a mod date of today, or NSLog the real path from your iOS app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems that I made a terrible mistake in passing a path with file name into the download method I called. Still I learned something from you. Thanks again! :)