# PDF File Not Launching on WKWEbView in iOS Swift

Tags: wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have downloaded pdf file from the Webservices and downloaded into Document Directory as shown below

file:///Users/iOS/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C4003255-3946-4AD1-FEFG-8B4D6EE70F65/data/Containers/Data/Application/S61AZ-051B-40AB-B7A1-B7FD37A2D3C3/Documents/Sample.pdf

While launching this path on WKWebView in iOS Simulator then it is working like pdf file showing all pages but
While Launching this path in iOS Devices then im facing the issue is: "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted".

How to fix this issue in iOS devices ?

is there any permission have to provide to devices ?

please fix this issue

Comment: The path that you showed starts with `file:///Users/iOS/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`. Such a path can only be opened on the respective simulator. On a device, a different path has to be used.

Comment: Yes you are right but, while launching  the content on iOS devices then path will be changes asper device standards but launching not working only in iOS device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263008/ios-cant-read-file-located-in-documents-directory.                                                                                            
      See this url link. This is the exact issue im facing in iOS devices, which is working fine in iOS simulator. please let me know how to solve it.